# Using preprocess node variable in page.tpl.php

Tags: nodes, theming, 7

I've set up a couple of variables in my `template_preprocess_node()`. How can I access them within a page template? I can access the `$node` variable, but it doesn't seem to have been preprocessed.

How can I force preprocessing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The node variable for page templates is set in template_preprocess_page
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6
You should override that function in your theme

Comment: I know, but since I've already overridden preprocess_node, I'd rather prefer not to duplicate the code, and use the preprocessed node within the page.

Comment: Wrap your code in a function, I'm pretty sure that's the only way to go.

Comment: @Eelke: In `template_preprocess_page` can you access fields of the node?

Comment: Actually I can answer that myself.  Yes you can.  In Drupal 7 they seem to be available as `$variables['node']->field_example`.